# Possible Stack Overflow phishing site - Searchalleasy.com

Tags: discussion, scraping

Searchalleasy.com seems to have cloned StackOverflow and is actually coming up higher in some Google searches (didn't even realize at first that it wasn't Stack Overflow).

Seems to be a very current (or active) scrape and urls all work in same format
http://www.searchalleasy.com/questions

Who Is (created 2015-04-03):
http://whois.domaintools.com/searchalleasy.com

Comment: I already reported the site about a week ago.